# Removing page numbers after references

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, back-referencing

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to remove the page number hyperlinks displayed after references in the bibliography, for example:

> [39] E. Economou, Green's Functions in Quantum Physics. Springer, 3rd
> ed., 2006. **7, 26**

I found on a previous answer that the usual culprit is **\usepackage{hyperref}**

in the preamble, but after disabling this I still have the problem. I can't see any other reference package that might be enabling this option, but here is the preamble and the bit where I insert my refernces. I also tried changing reference styles but this didn't remove the page numbers either!

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{Latex/Classes/PhDthesisPSnPDF}

\include{Latex/Macros/MacroFile1}

\usepackage{enumerate}  
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}   
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{cancel}
\graphicspath{{./Images/}}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{caption}
```

.....

```
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is lurking in `Latex/Macros/MacroFile1`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Just some macros for repeated insertion of figures etc, they aren't used in my code so I've removed them just now and my results are still the same.

Comment: Perhaps you should also remove hyperref option of biblatex package (for example : \usepacakage[style=authoryear-comp,hyperref]{biblatex}). You MWE is incomplet so I can see if you have this option or not.

Comment: Answers should preferably be posted as a an answer, not added into the question. Then you can also accept your own answer, which marks the question as solved. (You may have to wait a few hours before you're allowed to do that though.)

Answer (score 4):

Quoting the OP:

> PROBLEM FIXED
>
> The problem was found within the custom class I was using, {Latex/Classes/PhDthesisPSnPDF} as I was using the CUEDThesisPSnPDF template for my thesis. Within the class I searched for pagebackref in the hyperref package and just added "= false", so it now reads `pagebackref = false`,